# fs.writeFile in a promise, asynchronous-synchronous stuff

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, file-io, synchronization, es6-promise

I need some help with my code. I'm new at Node.js and have a lot of trouble with it.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Fetch a .txt with Amazon products (ASINs) ;
2. Fetch all products using the [amazon-product-api](https://github.com/t3chnoboy/amazon-product-api) package;
3. Save each product in a .json file.

My code is not working. I think I messed up with this asynchronous-synchronous stuff - help me!

```
var amazon = require('amazon-product-api');
var fs = require('fs');

var client = amazon.createClient({
    awsId: "XXX",
    awsSecret: "XXX",
    awsTag: "888"
});

var array = fs.readFileSync('./test.txt').toString().split('\n');
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
     var ASIN = array[i];

    client.itemLookup({
            domain: 'webservices.amazon.de',
            responseGroup: 'Large',
            idType: 'ASIN',
            itemId: ASIN
        })
        .then(function(results) {
            fs.writeFile(ASIN + '.json', JSON.stringify(results), function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("JSON saved");
                }
            })

            return results;

        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

Comment: After 6 years, 10 answers and hundreds of votes, still no one has noticed that the for-loop ALWAYS exits in the first iteration because of the `return` statement! I'm going to edit the question and remove `return`, but as a sanity check it would be great if one of the highly voter answerers confirmed my edit. It would also be great if one of you improved the title of the quesion, making it more specific.

Comment: Even better if the answers had more of the question's context, e.g. rewriting the full for-loop, at least at the end of their answers.

Answer (score 280):

## As of 2019...

...the correct answer is to use async/await with **[the native `fs` promises module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) included in node**. Upgrade to Node.js 10 or 11 (already supported by major cloud providers) and do this:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

// This must run inside a function marked `async`:
const file = await fs.readFile('filename.txt', 'utf8');
await fs.writeFile('filename.txt', 'test');
```

Do not use third-party packages and do not write your own wrappers, that's not necessary anymore.

#### No longer experimental

Before Node `11.14.0`, you would still get a warning that this feature is experimental, but it works just fine and it's the way to go in the future. Since `11.14.0`, the feature is no longer experimental and is production-ready.

#### What if I prefer `import` instead of `require`?

It works, too - but only in Node.js versions where this feature is not marked as experimental.

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

(async () => {
    await fs.writeFile('./test.txt', 'test', 'utf8');
})();
```

Comment: Heads up this is marked as experimental as of 10.9.0

Comment: For Node 8.x use the mz/fs library for using fs with async await.

Comment: To avoid the message: `ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental`, just use `node --no-warnings app.js`

Comment: there is no warning in node 11.x+

Comment: This should be the correct answer as long as you're not stuck on an old version of Node. `async` and `await` is the (beautiful) future of handling asynchronous stuff.

Comment: Pretty sure there is an error here in the async version. Should be 
```
const file = await fs.readFile('filename.txt', 'utf8');
await fs.writeFile('filename.txt', 'test');
```

Comment: If you use `import` you can also use `import fs from 'fs/promises';`

Comment: `fs.writeFile` needs a callback now

Comment: @PascalBelloncle see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff#comment126786455_31978347). Since you seem to be a Node expert, can you edit this answer to be more complete, e.g. to show it in the full context of the question's code... e.g. within the for-loop?

Comment: @JulianWagner What do you mean by callback? `fs.writeFile()` works without `await` as opposed to `fs.readFile` which needs await. And the `encoding` third parameter is not needed, at least for german's umlauts.

Comment: Nowadays, `import fs from 'fs/promises';` is the nicest way to write it.

Answer (score 65):

Because `fs.writefile` is a traditional asynchronous callback - you need to follow the promise spec and return a new promise wrapping it with a resolve and rejection handler like so:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.writeFile("<filename.type>", data, '<file-encoding>', function(err) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(data);
    });
});
```

So in your code you would use it like so right after your call to `.then()`:

```
 .then(function(results) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            fs.writeFile(ASIN + '.json', JSON.stringify(results), function(err) {
               if (err) reject(err);
               else resolve(data);
            });
    });
  }).then(function(results) {
       console.log("results here: " + results)
  }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log("error here: " + err);
  });
```

Comment: Starting in Node v8 you can use util.promisify() to convert the fs I/O functions into promises, e.g.
`const util = require('util');`
`const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);`
`...`
`return writeFile(ASIN + '.json', JSON.stringify(results));`

Comment: Starting in Node v10 you can use `await fs.` directly, check out my answer below

Answer (score 63):

say

```
const util = require('util')
const fs_writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)
```

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

this is less prone to bugs than the top-voted answer

Comment: `util.promisify` was added in node.js version 8. Thought this info might be helpful for people thinking of using it.

Answer (score 25):

Finally, the latest node.js release v10.3.0 has natively supported fs promises.

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises; // or require('fs/promises') in v10.0.0
fsPromises.writeFile(ASIN + '.json', JSON.stringify(results))
  .then(() => {
    console.log('JSON saved');
  })
  .catch(er => {
    console.log(er);
  });
```

You can check the official documentation for more details.
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: `const fs = require('fs').promises`, not /promises

Comment: @LeonardPauli Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm getting a **TypeError**: `Cannot read property 'writeFile' of undefined`. Possibly, because this method does not have a constructor for handling binary Strings?: `fsPromises.writeFile(tempFile, response.auioContent, 'binary').then(() => {
        console.log('Audio content written to file: ' + tempFile);
        return { filePath: "filePath" }
      })`

Comment: It appears `fs.writeFile(...)` returns a promise now... May someone please confirm? The `then(...)` portion of my code is being reached.

Comment: @Lewis see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff#comment126786455_31978347). Could you also edit your answer to be more complete, e.g. to show it in the full context of the question's code... e.g. within the for-loop?

Comment: As of today, I do not see any added value to the top vote answer. Is it possible to remove this answer?

Answer (score 18):

If you want to import the promise based version of `fs` as an ES module you can do:

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs'

await fs.writeFile(...)
```

---

As soon as node v14 is released (see this [PR](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/31553)), you can also use

```
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises'
```

Comment: see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff#comment126786455_31978347). Could you also edit your answer to be more complete, e.g. to show it in the full context of the question's code... e.g. within the for-loop?

Answer (score 15):

What worked for me was fs.promises.

Example One:

```js
const fs = require("fs")

fs.promises
  .writeFile(__dirname + '/test.json', "data", { encoding: 'utf8' })
  .then(() => {
    // Do whatever you want to do.
    console.log('Done');
  });
```

Example Two. Using Async-Await:

```js
const fs = require("fs")

async function writeToFile() {
  await fs.promises.writeFile(__dirname + '/test-22.json', "data", {
    encoding: 'utf8'
  });

  console.log("done")
}

writeToFile()
```

Answer (score 6):

### 2023, Node v16+, ESM, `import`, using promises

(I've also refactored the code a bit to avoid nested `try..catch` blocks, YMMV.

```
import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises';

async function doFile(filepath) { // choose a better name than `doFile` for your use case!!
    try {
        const fileData = await fs.readFile(filepath, {encoding: 'utf8'});
        var array = fileData.toString().split('\n');
        for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            var ASIN = array[i];
            let results = await doClientStuff(args); // e.g. client.itemLookup
            await saveResults(ASIN, results);
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error?.message ?? error?.toString()); // or however you extract your error msg
    }
}
async function saveResults(ASIN, results) {
    try {
        await fs.writeFile(ASIN + '.json', JSON.stringify(results));
        console.log("JSON saved");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error?.message ?? error?.toString()); // or however you extract your error msg
    }
}
await doFile('./test.txt');
```

This uses the OP's desire to us a `fs` default import. I personally would change it to import only your individual functions and remove the `fs.` references to enable esm tree-shaking:

```
import { readFile, writeFile } from 'node:fs/promises';

const fileData = await readFile(filepath, {encoding: 'utf8'}); // fs. removed

await writeFile(ASIN + '.json', JSON.stringify(results)); // fs. removed
```

### further info

- From [`readFile` docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options):

> If no encoding is specified (using options.encoding), the data is
> returned as a  object. Otherwise, the data will be a string.

Refer to [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#file-system) for additional info, including alternative usage with sync/callbacks. Be sure to select your correct version in the docs for your Node environment.

Answer (score 4):

**Update** *Sept 2017*: `fs-promise` has been deprecated in favour of [`fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra).

---

I haven't used it, but you could look into [fs-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promise). It's a node module that:

> Proxies all async fs methods exposing them as Promises/A+ compatible
>   promises (when, Q, etc). Passes all sync methods through as values.

Answer (score 3):

Use `require('fs/promises')`

```js
var fs = require('fs/promises'); // Since 11.14.0
var path = require('path'); // to help us to join better the paths

var content = JSON.stringify(["this is your content"]); // Must be a string to be written.

fs
  .writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'test.json'), content, { encoding: 'utf8' })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Write is done!');
  });
```

Example using async/await

```js
var fs = require('fs/promises'); // Since 11.14.0
var path = require('path'); // to help us to join better the paths

var content = JSON.stringify(["this is your content"]); // Must be a string to be written.

(async function autorun(){
  
  await fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'test.json'), content, { encoding: 'utf8' })  
  console.log('Write is done!');

})() // This is called a IIFE: Immediately invoked function expression
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const util = require('util')
const fs = require('fs');

const fs_writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)

fs_writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js')
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

For easy to use asynchronous convert all callback to promise use some library like "bluebird" .

```
      .then(function(results) {
                fs.writeFile(ASIN + '.json', JSON.stringify(results), function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("JSON saved");
                        return results;
                    }
                })


            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

Try solution with promise (bluebird)

```
var amazon = require('amazon-product-api');
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var client = amazon.createClient({
    awsId: "XXX",
    awsSecret: "XXX",
    awsTag: "888"
});


var array = fs.readFileSync('./test.txt').toString().split('\n');
Promise.map(array, function (ASIN) {
    client.itemLookup({
        domain: 'webservices.amazon.de',
        responseGroup: 'Large',
        idType: 'ASIN',
        itemId: ASIN
    }).then(function(results) {
        fs.writeFile(ASIN + '.json', JSON.stringify(results), function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("JSON saved");
                return results;
            }
        })
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `fs.writeFileSync` inside the try/catch block as below.

```
var fs = require('fs');
try {
    const file = fs.writeFileSync(ASIN + '.json', JSON.stringify(results))
    console.log("JSON saved");
    return results;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: never do this! writeFileSync is a synchronous function that halts the execution of the script and makes the app slow and defeats the entire purpose of using JS on server side. im downvoting, sorry.