# Node - Write JSON result to a file after a promise

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request-promise

I am using request-promise to fetch data from an api. I need to write the results to a json file. Following code doesn't write anything to the file.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
rp(empOptions)
    .then(function (repos) {
        employees= repos;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            fs.writeFile('../employees.json', JSON.stringify(employees), function(err) {
                if (err) reject(err);
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // API call failed...
    });
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff?answertab=votes#tab-top) also, but that didn't worked out either.

Comment: Have you checked if repos contains data in your `.then` method?

Comment: Yes, it contains data.

Comment: Try removing the return new Promise. You're not returning data with the resolve method of the Promise anyhow. The fs.writeFile should work by itself in this situation.

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried something like `var stringifiedJSON = JSON.stringify(employees);` and then pass the `stringifiedJSON` variable into the `fs.writeFile()` method?

Comment: Yes, tried that also Kyle

Comment: Well then I'm sorry I can't help. There is nothing wrong with the format of the `fs.writeFile()` method. Try this example `fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});` That is straight from the File System documentation. Replace 'message.text' with the location you want the file and see if it works.

Comment: Using ../employees.json actually created the file out of the project folder. Actually the file was created earlier too. Thanks for clearing this up. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

Best and easy way to write on file:

```
.then(function(results) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.appendFileSync('myurlss2.json', results, function(err) {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else resolve(results)
        })
    })
})
.then(function(results) {
    console.log("results here: " + results)
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log("error here: " + err)
});
```

Comment: Full Code :    .then(function(results) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       fs.appendFileSync('myurlss2.json',results, function(err) {
               if (err) reject(err);
               else 
      {resolve(results);

            
      }
   });
    });
  }).then(function(results) {
       console.log("results here: " + results)
  }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log("error here: " + err);
  });

Comment: instead of adding code in a comment, it is better to edit the answer,