# How can I execute a callback only when my data push is complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have run into quite an annoying issue with my Javascript code due to its synchronous nature, in short the problem is I need to dump a load of data into an array.

This array is then written directly into a JSON file.

```
function main(callback)  {
  myarrary = [] 

  //run some SQL query via stored procedure

  for (result in query) {

    myarray.push({

      //my data is entered here
    })
  }

  let data = JSON.stringify({myarray: somedata}, null, 4)
  fs.writeFileSync('testingjson.json', data)
  callback();
}
main(another_function)
```

My issue is that the data dump and callback are executed immediately, as such no data is transferred to the file and 'another_function` relies on data being there so that doesn't work either.

Therefore I need the dump to wait for the loop to finish appending `myarray`

I have also tried entering the dump and callback into my for loop however they execute on the first iteration.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should **not** write file in *sync* if you need callbacks?

Comment: @Nishant please can you elaborate?

Comment: Are you running `node`?

Comment: @Nishant I am yes

Comment: Try `fs.writeFile(filename, data[, options], callback)`.

Comment: @Nishant that sounds more like what I am looking for

Comment: Problem 1) This code should work fine, see if there are exceptions? Put a debugger and see if the data is getting written. 2) You can use `async` for this kind of thing, that is how it is done unless you only have one thing to do like in a simple script.

Comment: @Nishant , data can be written to the file if it is inside of the loop, however this isn't a solution as the file is opened thousands of times and slows the script down. I will look into an `async` solution

Comment: Your `run some SQL query via stored procedure` could also be asnyc and without know that, there's no knowing wether `myarrary` is an empty array (it could very well be looking at your code) or contains the data you expect!

Comment: @1556089774 If i place the dump in my loop it will send all of the data - so data can be written to myarray, however this isnt practical as it opens and writes the json for every loop iteration. I want the data to be dumped in the json once `myarray` is complete

Answer (score 1):

Functionally your current code looks fine, except that you should not call the function as *callback* unless it is an *asynchronous* function.

Callbacks are usually associated with asynchronous API's. It is useful if you want `main(...)` to return immediately so that you can just continue with something else. Since that is the default behavior, the API is

```
fs.writeFile(filename, data[, options], callback)
```

So to convert your program to async, you need:

```
fs = require("fs");

function main(callback)  {

    // Oops. Why is query executed synchronously?

    query = sqlSync() ;

    fs.writeFile('delete.json', "Data", callback);

}

main(() => console.log("Done"))
```

You can also convert SQL calls to async if your API's support that (since it is an I/O operation).

Once you are comfortable with normal callbacks, you can try using `promise` or `async-await` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff).

Comment: This IS the solution maybe @EcSync accept it ? I got this in my email as unanswered question but there's nothing to add or improve as far as I can see !

Answer (score 0):

if you have two methods who are returning callbacks you can use Promise.all([]). Here in Promise.all() you can write your database calls or other functions which are resolving/rejecting anything. From there you can get them in res object.