# How to execute the java script code sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Every day i m learning new things in javascript(nodejs) however one thing that's quite confusing for me is the concept of async-await.

Need a little help in managing the sequence of execution in below code. here's how it should execute
I m writing a daily script which should read file value from local system ( file contains : last run date).
put a new value in the file after it finishes reading the file(File should store current date).

```
fs = require('fs');
path = require('path');
let todaysDate = new Date();

async function checkPreviousRunDate() {
  console.log("Step 1 : Today's Date: " + todaysDate.getDate());

  filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'lastrundetail.txt');
  var filedata;
  await fs.readFile(filePath, {
    encoding: 'utf-8'
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Step 2 :Last run was done on(MM/DD/YYYY): ' + data);
      let lastrunDate = new Date(data);
      const diffTime = Math.abs(todaysDate - lastrunDate);
      const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      console.log("Step 3 :Its been " + diffDays + " day(s) Since the last run");
      return data;
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      return "";
    }
  });

}

async function storeTodaysDateinLastRunFile() {
  console.log("Step 4 : Finally Saving the todays date in last run file: ");
  await fs.writeFile("lastrundetail.txt", todaysDate, function(err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('Step 5 : Saved the record in file');
  });
  return todaysDate;
}

const main = async () => {
  let lastrunDate = await checkPreviousRunDate();
  let storedDate = await storeTodaysDateinLastRunFile();
}
main();
```

Output :

```
Step 1 : Today's Date: 4
Step 4 : Finally Saving the todays date in last run file:
Step 5 : Saved the record in file
Step 2 :Last run was done on(MM/DD/YYYY): Fri Dec 04 2020 13:10:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Step 3 :Its been 1 day(s) Since the last run
```

Expected Output :

```
Step 1 : Today's Date: 4
Step 2 :Last run was done on(MM/DD/YYYY): Fri Dec 04 2020 13:06:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Step 3 :Its been 1 day(s) Since the last run
Step 4 : Finally Saving the todays date in last run file:
Step 5 : Saved the record in file
```

Comment: `fs.readFile` doesn't return a Promise, so, you can't `await` it - same goes for `fs.writeFile`

Comment: You should probably be using [the promise API for FS](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) rather than the callback one. `await fs.readFile` doesn't really wait for the whole reading of file to finish.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fs.writeFile in a promise, asynchronous-synchronous stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff)

Answer (score 1):

`await` is only useful on promises.

However `fs.readFile` returns `undefined` and therefore it does not make any sense to use it on it.

[image]

If you use VSC you can hover over and see that it returns `void` which means nothing which means `undefined`

What you can do is to promisfy `readFile` and `writeFile`. For this you can use `new Promise()`

```
function write(date) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.writeFile("lastrundetail.txt", date, function(err) {
      if (err) return rej(err);
      res("Step 5 : Saved the record in file");
    });
  });
}
```

This function will return you an promise. You can either resolve with `res` or reject with `rej`

[image]

Now you can see it returns an promise

On error you reject otherwise you resolve the promise.

Same for `readFile`

```
function read(filePath) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.readFile(
      filePath,
      {
        encoding: "utf-8"
      },
      function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("Step 2 :Last run was done on(MM/DD/YYYY): " + data);
          let lastrunDate = new Date(data);
          const diffTime = Math.abs(todaysDate - lastrunDate);
          const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
          console.log(
            "Step 3 :Its been " + diffDays + " day(s) Since the last run"
          );
          res(data);
        } else {
          rej(err);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Here i resolve the `data`. Later when we use `let data = await read(...)` it will return us our data.
Now both functions returning an pending promise.

Now it makes sense to use `await` on our functions

```
async function checkPreviousRunDate() {
  console.log("Step 1 : Today's Date: " + todaysDate.getDate());
  filePath = path.join(__dirname, "lastrundetail.txt");
  let data = await read(filePath);
  console.log(data);
}

async function storeTodaysDateinLastRunFile() {
  console.log("Step 4 : Finally Saving the todays date in last run file: ");
  await write(todaysDate);
  return todaysDate;
}
```

In case some error occure you can wrap it in an `try / catch` which you usually should do. This will catch the `rej` error

```
async function checkPreviousRunDate() {
  console.log("Step 1 : Today's Date: " + todaysDate.getDate());

  filePath = path.join(__dirname, "lastrundetail.txt");
  try {
     let data = await read(filePath);
     console.log(data);
  catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
  }
}
```