# Wait for one function to finish before continuing?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

When running the following code tidied in functions or not, it still writes to my file incorrectly. One thing that did work was wrapping those functions inside of a setTimeout method, with the seconds somewhere around 10. I just didn't like the idea of hardcoding those values and taking anymore time to complete than it should. **What's a better way of going about this?** I need help understanding async/await a little more as you can tell but what better way than to fail and ask for help!

```js
  genPriceChangeScripts: async () => {
    const priceScript = `...`;

    const changeData = await get24hrChange();

    const globalCmds = [];
    const globalPol = [];

    const filtered = changeData.filter(function (item) {
      return (
        !item.symbol.includes("BTCUSDT_") && !item.symbol.includes("ETHUSDT_")
      );
    });

    async function scripts() {
      filtered.forEach((e) => {
        const data = e.symbol;

        const change = priceScript.replace("CHANGE", data);

        fs.writeFile(
          `../scripts/price_change/${data.toLowerCase()}_price_change.sh`,
          change,
          function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
          }
        );
      });
      console.log("scripts finished");
    }
    scripts();

    async function commands() {
      for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
        var pushCmds = `"#($CURRENT_DIR/scripts/price_change/${filtered[
          i
        ].symbol.toLowerCase()}_price_change.sh)"`;
        globalCmds.push(pushCmds);
      }

      const commands = globalCmds.join("\n");

      const cmdsWithComment = commands.concat("\n#CHANGE3");

      fs.readFile("../binance.tmux", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        const addCmds = data.replace("#CHANGE1", cmdsWithComment);

        fs.writeFile("../binance.tmux", addCmds, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
        });
      });
      console.log("cmds finished");
    }
    commands();

    async function pols() {
      for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
        const pushPol = `"\\#{${filtered[
          i
        ].symbol.toLowerCase()}_price_change}"`;
        globalPol.push(pushPol);
      }

      const pol = globalPol.join("\n");

      const polWithComment = pol.concat("\n#CHANGE4");

      fs.readFile("../binance.tmux", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        const addPol = data.replace("#CHANGE2", polWithComment);

        fs.writeFile("../binance.tmux", addPol, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
        });
      });
      console.log("pols finished");
    }
    pols();

    return prompt.end();
  },
```

Comment: `async function`s return a `Promise`, so `await scripts();` would be the syntax, yet your `scripts` function is pointlessly `async` since you are not `await`ing anything within it. `fs.writeFile` should be `return`ed.

Comment: @StackSlave I would love to see an answer that solves this, great points!

Comment: you are using the callback version of fs.writeFile and fs.readFile - use the promise version `import * as fs from 'fs/promises';` rather than `import * as fs from 'fs';` - then you can await those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that making a function `async` doesn't make it automatically wait for anything asynchronous going on inside it

`async`/`await` is syntax "sugar" for working with Promises, and Promises **only**

So, if you use the promise version of writeFile/readFile like so

```
import * as fs from 'fs/promise';
```

you can write your code as follows

```
genPriceChangeScripts: async() => {
    const priceScript = `...`;

    const changeData = await get24hrChange();

    const globalCmds = [];
    const globalPol = [];

    const filtered = changeData.filter(function (item) {
        return (!item.symbol.includes("BTCUSDT_") && !item.symbol.includes("ETHUSDT_"));
    });

    async function scripts() {
        const promises = filtered.map((e) => {
            const data = e.symbol;

            const change = priceScript.replace("CHANGE", data);

            return fs.writeFile(`../scripts/price_change/${data.toLowerCase()}_price_change.sh`, change);
        });
        await Promise.all(promises);
        console.log("scripts finished");
    }
    await scripts();

    async function commands() {
        for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
            var pushCmds = `"#($CURRENT_DIR/scripts/price_change/${filtered[i].symbol.toLowerCase()}_price_change.sh)"`;
            globalCmds.push(pushCmds);
        }

        const commands = globalCmds.join("\n");

        const cmdsWithComment = commands.concat("\n#CHANGE3");

        const data = await fs.readFile("../binance.tmux", "utf-8");
        const addCmds = data.replace("#CHANGE1", cmdsWithComment);
        await fs.writeFile("../binance.tmux", addCmds);
        console.log("cmds finished");
    }
    await commands();

    async function pols() {
        for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
            const pushPol = `"\\#{${filtered[i].symbol.toLowerCase()}_price_change}"`;
            globalPol.push(pushPol);
        }
        const pol = globalPol.join("\n");
        const polWithComment = pol.concat("\n#CHANGE4");
        const data = await fs.readFile("../binance.tmux", "utf-8");
        const addPol = data.replace("#CHANGE2", polWithComment);
        await fs.writeFile("../binance.tmux", addPol);
        console.log("pols finished");
    }
    await pols();

    return prompt.end();
},
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to `await` the [File System](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) operations in order to wait for the asynchronous functions to return a response before proceeding.

`await fs.readFile` and `await fs.writeFile`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff#answer-52094177) for further explanation and examples.

This is in addition to adding `await` to your other `async` functions to propagate the promise chain correctly.

Answer (score -2):

Not that I'm saying all your code works, but here are the kind changes I would make to get you in the correct direction:

```
// code above
  function scripts(){
    const a = [];
    filtered.forEach(e=>{
      const data = e.symbol, change = priceScript.replace('CHANGE', data);
      a.push(new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        fs.writeFile(`../scripts/price_change/${data.toLowerCase()}_price_change.sh`,
          change,
          err=>{
            if(err){
              reject(err);
            }
            else{
              resolve();
            }
          }
        );
      }));
    });
    return Promise.all(a);
  }
  await scripts();
// code below
```

Well... actually I would define the function somewhere else or not use it at all, but I think this is what you need to see.

Comment: fs.writeFile doesn't return a promise unless you import the promise version. and in that case, you don't provide a callback argument to writeFile

Comment: @Bravo, that's an easy fix. Code will reflect. Give me a couple of minutes.