# How to wait for the file to get created before sending request back to client using res.sendFile()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a file creator block which writes the file to disk, and then sends the file to the client.

But the response is sent before the file is getting written.

```js
  carbone.render("./template.odt", data, options, (err, ress) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    var paths = `./static/reports/report-${timestamp}.pdf`;
    fs.writeFileSync(paths, ress);
    process.exit();
  });

  res.sendFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "..", "static", "reports", `report-${timestamp}.pdf`)
  );
```

What is the solution so that sendFile waits for the file to be written and then fetches it?

Comment: You are using `writeFileSync()` meaning the write was a sucess after that call. you can just return it after it

Comment: I've tried adding the response right after `writeFileSync`, but it still doesn't send the file
The server sends `Error: socket hang up`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the callback function is for. *carbone.render* renders a template and when it's done returns result to the callback function. JS will not wait for the *carbone.render* to complete before moving to *res.sendFile*. You can move the sending part inside the callback function.

Comment: removing the process.exit() and adding it inside the render function after the writeFileSync line worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add sendFile code into callback function of carbone.render or else you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff) question.