# Why doesn't this promise work inside async method?

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, callback

I just started learning node.js and am trying to figure out how promises work.

I'm already familiar with async/await and am using axios to fetch data. Once the data is fetched, I want to write the data to a file and when that's done, log `successful` to the console.

To learn more about promises, I want to make my own that logs `++` to the console and then integrate that promise into the above.

So I wrote this, but when I run it with `node`, it only logs `++`. I tried some variants, but don't understand what's happening.

```
const second = async () => {
  console.log('++')
}

const processData = async () => {  
  const req = await axios.get('http://localhost:5004/swagger');
  let reqJson = JSON.stringify(req.data);
  fs.writeFile('newSwagger.json', reqJson, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('successful');
  });
}

let firstPromise = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
  second(() => {
    resolve(processData());
  });
});

firstPromise.then(function() {
  second();
});
```

Why does the above code not produce the following output?

```
++
successful
++
```

Comment: The code in the question will throw a number of syntax errors. You will also find coding easier if you use proper indentation, so that blocks are easily recognizable at a glance.

Comment: `second()` is a function that takes no arguments.  So passing a callback to it will NEVER call that callback, thus `firstPromise` will never resolve.

Comment: Could you help describe what your desired/expected output is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs").promises;

const second = async () => {
  console.log('++')
}

const processData = async () => {  
  const req = await axios.get('http://google.com');
  let reqJson = JSON.stringify(req.data);

  try {
    await fs.writeFile('newSwagger.json', reqJson);
    console.log('succesful');
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}

let firstPromise = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
  second().then(processData).then(resolve);
});

firstPromise.then(second)
  .then(() => console.log('finished'));
```

results in

```
++
successful
++
finished
```

### Explanations

`second` is a parameterless function that *returns* a promise. It isn't itself a promise. This means that when you're doing `second(() => resolve(processData()))`, you're never actually invoking the processData function. You're just executing the `second` function and handing it a function that *would* run `processData` but instead it never executes the passed in function as something like this would:

```
const second = async (callback) {
  callback()
}
```

Also the `async` keyword for `second` is unnecessary since you're not using an `await` within. The `async` keyword basically is syntactic sugar which wraps the function into returning a promise kind of like:

```
const second = () => {
  console.log('++')
  return new Promise();
```

so in my corrected example, that's why I can suddenly do `second().then(doSomething)` however because there's nothing awaited within, it's the exact same as just `second()` followed by `doSomething()`.

Also, the `resolve` inside of `new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...)` is kind of like setting a `return`, but it doesn't necessarily *wait* for anything. So if you want the second '++' to *wait* until `processData` is completely done and 'successful' is logged, you need to chain off the processData's returned promise like `.then(processData).then(resolve)`.

Finally if you do the above, you may still notice that you don't see your 'successful' string printed - or well you might *sometimes* and at unexpected times. This is because you've also added callbacks into the mix along with promises and async/await. the ultimate effect being that your console.log('successful') will run at some point but you have nothing waiting for it nor chained after it. You could promisify the call to `fs.writeFile` yourself but you could also just use the built-in promise version of node's `fs` module - [see this for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff).

If it helps focus only on how the promises work(without async/await and callbacks also), here's a version with only promises to achieve the same resulting output:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs").promises;

const second = () => {
  console.log('++')
}

const processData = () => {  
  return new Promise(
    resolve => axios.get('http://google.com').then((req) => {
        let reqJson = JSON.stringify(req.data);
        return reqJson;
    }).then((reqJson) => {
        fs.writeFile('newSwagger.json', reqJson).then(resolve);
    }).then(() => console.log('successful'))
  );
}

second();
processData().then(() => {
    second();
    console.log('finished')
})
```